# Customised data range

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and looking for some help to create a function which allows the user to input a customized date range. I have printed my efforts thus far, but can't seem to get it working.

```
def customised_range():
    '''Allows the user to create a customised date range'''
    print("{:=^40}".format("Date Menu"))
    start = input("Please enter a start date (DD-MM-YYYY): ")
    base = date.datetime.strptime(start, "%02d-%02d-%04d")
    if base >  date.datetime.now():
        print("Invalid input(Future Date entered)! Please try again.")
        customised_range()
    end_date = input("Please enter an end date (DD-MM-YYYY): "
    end = data.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%02d-%02d-%04d")
    if end > date.datetime.now() or end < base:
        print("Invalid input, Please try again!")
        customised_range()
```

Comment: what is your goal? what would be the input? the desired output? what does not work? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The goal is for the user to input two dates within the last five years, and my program would be able to produce financial analysis based on these dates.